# How can i make this loop parallel in OpenMP?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

Hi everyone I got a question at the exam that I could not solve about parallel programming.
Can someone help me with this .

Question: For the following code segment, use OpenMP pragmas to make the loop parallel, or explain why the code segment is not suitable for parallel execution:

```html
flag = 0
for(i=0;(i<n) & (!flag);i++){
    a[i] = 2.3 *i;
    if(a[i]<b[i])flag = 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible with this loop due to `flag`. Regardless, see: [Loop Parallelism](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-loop.html).

Answer (score 1):

As written the loop cannot trivially be parallelised with OpenMP because the `test-expr` in the loop (i.e. `(i<n) & !flag`) does not conform with the OpenMP restrictions :-

```
test-expr 
    One of the following:
        var relational-op ub
        ub relational-op var
    relational-op 
        One of the following: <, <=, >, >=, !=
```

([OpenMP standard](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu45.html#:%7E:text=type%20var%20%3D%20lb-,test%2Dexpr,One%20of%20the%20following%3A,-var%20relational%2Dop)).
At a semantic level this is because the test on `flag` prevents the loop iteration count from being determinable at entry to the loop, which is what OpenMP requires.

In recent OpenMP standards there is a [`cancel` construct](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu111.html#x145-1570002.20.1) which could be used here, something like (untested, uncompiled code)

```
bool flag = false;

#pragma omp parallel for 
for(int i=0;(i<n);i++){
    a[i] = 2.3 *i;
    if (a[i]<b[i]) {
#pragma omp atomic write
        flag = true;
    }
#pragma omp cancel for if (flag)
}
```

However it seems unlikely that a loop with this little work in it will be profitable for parallelisation in a real code (rather than an exam question).

Comment: Your parallel version can give different result than serial one. The serial version stops at the **smallest** `i` where `b[i]>2.3*i`, but your parallel version  does not.  I think the only possibility to use parallelism here is to first find the smallest `i` where `b[i]>2.3*i` (or use `n` ), then fill array `a` in parallel.

Comment: Yes, @laci, you are right; I also made it impossible to tell, by making `i` have loop scope :-) (That's the disadvantage of these small, non-compilable, examples; it's hard to tell what they\re trying to do). If you want the first element parallelisation really makes little sense. (Your solution will work, but seems very unlikely to be faster than serial code...)